# Find max local value in a range

Tags: python, pandas, range, max

I've been struggling with a problem for some days and I can't find the way.

I just need to find the MAX value in a range, but this is a dynamic range looking 2 rows forward and the 2 previous rows if possible.  So for the first row I look only forward rows [0, 1, 2] but in row 5 I want to compare maxs of [3,4,5,6,7] and know if the maximum is in the observed row.

**Close // Expected output**

10
12
13  // Max

9
11
15
17  // Max

13
12
10

I've tried to do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    print(df['Close'].max() in range(i, i+2))
```

But I can't figure out how to create the new column and work with this range...

Comment: Could you add an example output dataframe with the new column added? That would make it clearer what you want (instead of simply marking 2 of the rows with max).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`rolling`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html):

```
df['Max5'] = df['Close'].rolling(5, center=True).max()
print(df)

# Output:
   Close  Max5
0     10   NaN
1     12   NaN
2     13  13.0
3      9  15.0
4     11  17.0
5     15  17.0
6     17  17.0
7     13  17.0
8     12   NaN
9     10   NaN
```

You can extract max rows:

```
>>> df.loc[df['Close'] == df['Max5'], 'Close']
2    13
6    17
Name: Close, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Rolling function is perfect in this problem, I highly appreciate your answer!!!

The code at the end looks like:

`df['Max5'] = df['Close'].rolling(5,center=True).max()`
`df['Min5'] = df['Close'].rolling(5,center=True).min()`
`df['TopBot'] = np.where(df['Close'] == df['Max5'], 'Top', np.where(df['Close'] == df['Min5'], 'Bot',''))`

So know I have a column 'TopBot' where I can see which are local tops or bots.

thanks

Comment: And `df['TopBot'] = np.select([df['Close'] == df['Max5'], df['Close'] == df['Min5']], ['Top', 'Bot'])`